# Google firebase callable web functions - returns {data: null}

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am currently trying to return some data from a mongodb database query using callable web firebase functions. The functions are called. However, the `fullName` function returns `{data: null}` in my browsers console.

I have also tried `return "test"` and that also returns the same value of `{data: null}`

I am completely unsure why this is. And when I attempt to console.log

```
            const data = {
                totalInfections: totalInfections,
                totalUsers: totalUsers,
                totalCommands: totalCommands,
                totalLiveInfections: totalLiveInfections,
                totalLiveInfectedChannels: totalLiveInfectedChannels
            }
            console.log(data)
            return data
```

Nothing comes up in my function logs (on my localhost), or in my terminal.

However, if I go to `http://localhost:5001/pandemic-8955f/us-central1/fullName` I get an error in my function logs which is

```
function[us-central1-fullName]
{
  "severity": "WARNING",
  "message": "Request has invalid method. GET"
}
function[us-central1-fullName]
{
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "message": "Invalid request, unable to process."
}

function[us-central1-fullName]
Finished "us-central1-fullName" in ~1s
```

I am unsure why this is occuring, and any pointers or advice would be very helpful.

```
exports.fullName = functions.https.onCall((lol, lol1) => {
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/?readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&ssl=false";
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("discord_pandemic");
        dbo.collection("ArrayStats").find().toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            const totalInfections = result[0].total_infections
            const totalUsers = result[0].total_users
            const totalCommands = result[0].total_commands
            const totalLiveInfections = result[0].total_live_infections
            const totalLiveInfectedChannels = result[0].total_live_infected_channels
            const data = {
                totalInfections: totalInfections,
                totalUsers: totalUsers,
                totalCommands: totalCommands,
                totalLiveInfections: totalLiveInfections,
                totalLiveInfectedChannels: totalLiveInfectedChannels
            }
            console.log(data)
            return data
        });
    });
});
```

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="fName" placeholder="First Name">
    <input type="text" id="lName" placeholder="Last Name">
    <button onClick="addName()"> Add Name </button>
    <script>
        function addName() {
            var fullName = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('fullName');
            //For the fullName we have defined that fullName takes some data as a parameter 
            fullName({}).then((result) => {
                console.log(result);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are asynchronous calls in your code, one to open the connection to Mongo, and then another one to load the data from Mongo. By the time the daa has loaded and your `return data` executes, the close `}` of your Function has long since executed - and nobody will ever see that return.

In most cases, you can bubble up the promise that you'd typically get back from the API you call when starting an asynchronous operation. But it seems that `MongoClient.connect` doesn't return a promise, so you'll have to constructor you own like this:

```
exports.fullName = functions.https.onCall((lol, lol1) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {  //  return a promise, so Cloud Functions knows to wait
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/?readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&ssl=false";
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("discord_pandemic");
        dbo.collection("ArrayStats").find().toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            const totalInfections = result[0].total_infections
            const totalUsers = result[0].total_users
            const totalCommands = result[0].total_commands
            const totalLiveInfections = result[0].total_live_infections
            const totalLiveInfectedChannels = result[0].total_live_infected_channels
            const data = {
                totalInfections: totalInfections,
                totalUsers: totalUsers,
                totalCommands: totalCommands,
                totalLiveInfections: totalLiveInfections,
                totalLiveInfectedChannels: totalLiveInfectedChannels
            }
            console.log(data)
            resolve(data); //  resolve the promise with the data for the user
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Since you're new to this asynchronous behavior, I highly recommend checking out:

- The Firebase documentation on [when Cloud Functions are terminated](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).

Comment: Thanks for explaining what I was doing wrong here. I notice now that was an issue.

I have made the changes which you have suggested. However, recently I have a new idea about another reason why its not working.

The new solution still returns `{data: null}` and i think this is due to the function not being called?
I have put a console.log() inside of the fullName function, and when I click the button, there is no console.log in the function logs.

But, the response still gets logged into the browsers console.

Comment: If the function returns a value, it seems that it's being invoked, or am I missing something? Anyway: here could be many more thing going wrong here, as you're integrating three complex pieces of technology. All I know is that what I explained above is definitely. problem in the code you posted.

Comment: You are right. It turns out that it's because I didn't have the  `// firebase.functions().useFunctionsEmulator("http://localhost:5001"); // test functions locally` as I was testing my functions locally. Thanks so much for the help !